# Recursively enumerable sets and Turing machines

Tags: turing-machines

Let L1 be a recursive language. Let L2 and L3 be languages that are recursively enumerable but not recursive. Which of the following statements is not necessarily true? (A) L2 – L1 is recursively enumerable. (B) L1 – L3 is recursively enumerable (C) L2 ∩ L1 is recursively enumerable (D) L2 ∪ L1 is recursively enumerable

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like the author wants to hire someone to prepare their homework.

Comment: So what have you tried so far to answer this question, and where are you stuck? As written, a plain answer to this plain question is unlikely to help anyone in the future.

Comment: I think the answer is B.
 L1 - L3 = L1 intersection ( Complement L3 ) L1 is recursive , L3 is recursively enumerable but not recursive 
But I'm not sure!

Comment: @RiyaK fair enough, you seem to have given the question an honest try. (Do consider accepting the answer if it answered your question. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is B.you should find the concrete examples of L1 and L3

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the answer is (B). You should find a concrete example of languages *L1* (a recursive language) and *L3* (a RE language) for which *L1-L3* is not RE.

Below are proofs that statements (A), (C), and (D) hold. I'm using the fact that [every recursive language is recursively enumerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_language), and [the well-known closure properties of RE languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language#Closure_properties).

(A) *L2 - L1 = L2 intersection (complement L1)* is recursively enumerable because *L1* is recursive, thus *(complement L1)* is recursively enumerable, and an intersection of RE languages is again a RE language. (In general, the complement of a RE language *L* is RE if and only if *L* is recursive.)

(B) *L1 - L3 = L1 intersection (complement L3)* need not be RE. (Exercise: find a counterexample, i.e., find concrete languages *L1* (recursive) and *L3* (RE) such that *L1-L3* is not RE.)

(C) *L2 intersection L1* is RE because both *L1* and *L2* are RE and we know that intersection of two RE languages is again a RE language.

(D) *L2 union L1* is RE because both *L1* and *L2* are RE and we know that union of two RE languages is again a RE language.

Answer (score 0):

L1-L3=L1 intresection need not be RE

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the answer is (B). You should find a concrete example of languages L1 (a recursive language) and L3 (a RE language) for which L1-L3 is not RE.